# Salesforce package upload failure "A change was made to the package after the upload was initiated. Upload the package again."

Tags: package, unmanaged-package

I created a package with a couple of flows and process builders. But when I try to upload it is failed.

The email alert states: `A change was made to the package after the upload was initiated. Upload the package again.`

And the error details of the upload states: 
`WebLink - New_Correspondence2`

Update: There is a component named "New_Correspondence2" which is a custom button

Comment: Have you just tried uploading again? It sounds like a transient error.

Comment: Yes it keeps showing the same error

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue?  I'm seeing a very similar thing now.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, I had a similar issue.

### My Solution

I updated the weblink formula to just be "/" (with the quotation marks).
Mine was a URL weblink.